# Как выводить от большего к меньшему из SQL в типе данных текст

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

У меня есть поле **`b`**
У меня есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM app_catalog_rotor_gotoviy ORDER BY `b` = '' ASC, `b` ASC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

В запросе я прошу вывести мне строки от меньшего к большему, при этом поля с пустотой в конце, все бы хорошо, но работает не очень корректно

Я например хотел бы получить такой результат:
30 120 150~160

Но получаю:
150~160 150 130 30

Я думаю это работало бы в случае если бы тип поля **`b`** было бы число, но тут текст.
И тип данных я не знаю какой подобрать, так-как у клиента есть выражения типа
130~170

Как решить подобную задачу?

Скорректирую запрос так-как посоветовал **Akina**

```
SELECT * FROM app_catalog_rotor_gotoviy ORDER BY c = '' ASC, c + 0 ASC, SUBSTRING_INDEX(c, '~', -1) + 0 LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

В этом поле могут быть значения

- 2
- 150
- 1.23
- 130~150
- 1.17~9.90
- 91.17~99.90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
ORDER BY b = '' ASC,                      -- пустые поля в конце
         b + 0 ASC,                       -- сортировать по первому числу
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(b, '~', -1) + 0  -- и по второму числу
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d228d2f546177f54cd19381b316cc46c

PS. `b = ''` **не** отправит в конец значения из 1 и более пробелов, только именно пустую строку. Если есть записи с пробелами - используй `ORDER BY TRIM(b) = '' ASC` .

Comment: Да это сработало в многих случаях, но например у меня так-же появился результат

Comment: 4.00
4.00
2
4.35
Хотя заводил от меньшего к большему

Comment: Откорректируйте fiddle, вставьте туда свои данные, воспроизведите проблему, дайте ссылку. Будем смотреть.

Comment: Скорректировал вопрос

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко Вот в упор не понимаю, где Вы умудрились найти проблему. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6af862c08f0e6790ffc43ac5051b225c - всё сортируется чётко по возрастанию.

Comment: Вот прикрепил скриншот того что получается на UI https://dropmefiles.com/CcTFx

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко ??? при чём тут какой-то скриншот? да ещё скриншот с веб-страницы? по дороге туда данные могли быть десять раз пересортированы промежуточными инстанциями. Тестируйте сам запрос, причём непосредственно через CLI. Вот если там будут проблемы с порядком отдачи записей - тогда и жалуйтесь на неверную работу приведённого кода.

Comment: Обсудил с клиентом, все правильно работает, вам спасибо огромное за ответ, благодаря вашему ответу я почти закрыл проект)